# How to export pdf attachment from soap response using groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

Although **soap** (free version) has an option to export document generated in response. Is there any groovy function to extract application/pdf file and store in my local folder ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tryed any solution?

Comment: @adalPaRi - I am new to groovy however know VB scripting. I couldn't find function which will extract a pdf file which comes along with soap response. However, I am able to save response in text file using groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should be able to save the attachment to a file.

Add the below script as `Script Assertion` to the current request step. Find the appropriate comments inline.

Source for the script is taken from [here](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Saving-attachments-automatically/m-p/880/highlight/true#M229)

```
/**
* Below script assertion will check 
* if the response is not null
* there is an attachment
* and saves file to the specified location, by default saves into system temp
* directory
**/
//change file name as needed
def fileName = System.getProperty('java.io.tmpdir')+'/test.pdf'

//Get the response and check if the response is not null
def response = messageExchange.response
assert null != response, "response is null"

//Create output stream
def outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName))

//Check if there is one attachment in the response
assert 1 == messageExchange.responseAttachments.length, "Response attachments count not matching"
def ins = messageExchange.responseAttachments[0]?.inputStream
if (ins) {
   //Save to file
   com.eviware.soapui.support.Tools.writeAll( outFile,  ins )
}
ins.close()
outFile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing script !! I am getting error as "No such property : responseAttachment for class:.."

Comment: Stacktrace please? The script provided to you has `messageExchange.responseAttachments`, not  `responseAttachment`. It is attachment list, so has `s`, but what you point is single. Have you used as it is? or modified? The answer provided was a tested sample for other type of file, so should not have any problem in this case.

Comment: Thanks for rechecking and revert back