# Save attachments from response in SoapUI

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I get 2 files in response of a `SOAP` request. I try to save these files with followig `Groovy` script. I use script as a script assertion for test step. First file is saved successfully in execution, but couldn't find second one.

```
def fileName = "C:\\<mydirectory>"+'/test.pdf'
def fileName1 = "C:\\<mydirectory>"+'/test1.pdf'
def response = messageExchange.response
assert null != response, "response is null"
def outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName))
def outFile1 = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName1))
def ins = messageExchange.responseAttachments[0]?.inputStream
def ins1 = messageExchange.responseAttachments[0]?.inputStream

if (ins) {
com.eviware.soapui.support.Tools.writeAll(outFile, ins)
}
ins.close()
outFile.close()

if (ins1) {
com.eviware.soapui.support.Tools.writeAll(outFile1, ins)
}
ins1.close()

outFile1.close()
```

Comment: Both `ins` and `ins1` are assigned the same `messageExchange.responseAttachments[0]`?

Comment: Also `if (ins1) {
com.eviware.soapui.support.Tools.writeAll(outFile1, ins)
}`. Should that be `writeAll(outFile1, ins1)`?

Comment: May be a duplicate. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619511/how-to-export-pdf-attachment-from-soap-response-using-groovy/39622044#39622044)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save attachments automatically in SoapUI with Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51613745/save-attachments-automatically-in-soapui-with-groovy)

Comment: @Rao : Similar, but in this question I use Groovy script in script assertion, not in a Groovy test step.

Comment: @plaidshirt, have you tried the solution provided in my first reply?

Comment: @SiKing : Your comment solved problem. Thanks!